# Cannot save SSIS package after logging in with different user profile

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an SSIS package which I've developed under my own user profile.
I now have a new datasource which only allows Windows Authentication to their SQL database, so I have to now login to my environment using this service account as I cannot provide SQL login cedentials.

Having now logged in with the Windows service account I have opened my SSIS Solution and made the changes to add my new data source, however when I try to save the package I get the error "Access to the path ...... is denied"

I've also tried just executing the package (to test so long) but am again prompted to save the package first, and then get the same error.

I've checked Windows Folder & File permissions to report on the effective rights of this username, and it shows that I have Full Control to the entire folder and subfolder.

I am now stumped.... Any ideas?

Comment: Can you login with the other ID and close the project if it is still opened?

Comment: Thanks Deepak, however I am working on the same workstation and have logged out of my personal user profile so as to login with this service account, so by implication then I presume as per your question that the project has indeed been closed because I closed SSDT when logging out of my profile?

Comment: Yes, it did close it. As per the error it certainly, looks like an access issue. Could you perform a quick test, copy and paste the project in some other location and try making some change (any change) and then save the package/project and see if it works or not?

Comment: Oh wow, thanks Deepak, it worked!! I copied t the root of my drive and edited the solution from this new location, and all works fine now.

How do I now mark your input as the answer to my problem?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Added it as an answer. All yours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly looks like an access issue. Please copy the project and save it in some other location and then try and perform the same set of operations. It should work.